# Unable to create an alias in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, alias

I'm having trouble selecting the following from a postgres database.

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
>
> LINE 33:    dv.Creative_Size AS "Ad_Format",

```
 SELECT(
        dv.Advertiser,
        dv.Advertiser_ID,
        dv.Advertiser_Currency,
        dv.Insertion_Order,
        dv.Line_Item,   
        dv.Ad_Date,
        dv.Device_Type,
        dv.Environment, 
        dv.Creative_Size AS "Ad_Format",
        dv.Impressions,
        dv.Clicks,  
        dv.Total_Conversions,       
        dv.Revenue,
        dv.First_Quartile_Views,    
        dv.Midpoint_Views,  
        dv.Third_Quartile_Views,
        dv.Complete_Views,  
        dv.Viewable_Impressions,
        dv.Measureable_Impressions
    )
    FROM master_data_dv360 AS dv;
```

The create statement for this table is (don't worry this is an intermediary table for importing from a CSV file):

```
CREATE TABLE master_data_dv360(
Advertiser varchar,
Advertiser_ID varchar,
Advertiser_Currency varchar,
Insertion_Order varchar,
Insertion_Order_ID varchar, 
Line_Item varchar,  
Line_Item_ID varchar,   
Ad_Date varchar,
Device_Type varchar,
Environment varchar,    
Creative_Size varchar,  
Floodlight_Activity_Name varchar,   
Floodlight_Activity_ID varchar, 
Impressions varchar,
Billable_Impressions varchar,   
Clicks varchar, 
Click_Rate varchar, 
Total_Conversions varchar,  
Post_Click_Conversions varchar, 
Post_View_Conversions varchar,  
Revenue varchar,
Media_Cost varchar, 
First_Quartile_Views varchar,   
Midpoint_Views varchar, 
Third_Quartile_Views varchar,   
Complete_Views varchar, 
Viewable_Impressions varchar,
Measureable_Impressions varchar,    
CM_Post_Click_Revenue varchar,  
CM_Post_View_Revenue varchar
```

);

Comment: Remove the `()` around your column list and it should work fine. `SELECT dv.Advertiser, ...`

Comment: Yep that did it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The parentheses in your `SELECT` list are interpreted as a *[row constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS)*:

> The key word `ROW` is optional when there is more than one expression in the list.

So your query returns only a single (composite) value, and you could only add an alias after the closing parenthesis.

But I assume that the parentheses are there by mistake: if you remove them, your query will not cause the error any more.

Comment: Yep, that did it, this was a portion of a query that I have created and I just had an extra set of parenthesis.